# Unable to populate checkbox from database data in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my Controller code.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.grp_id = new SelectList(db.tm_grp_group, "grp_id", "grp_name");
    ViewBag.perm_id = new SelectList(db.tm_perm_level, "perm_id", "perm_levelname");
    return View();
}
```

Below is my view code.

```
@model Permission.ts_grp_perm_mapping
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ts_grp_perm_mapping</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.grp_permid)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.grp_permid)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.grp_permid)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.grp_id, "tm_grp_group")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("grp_id", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.grp_id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.perm_id, "tm_perm_level")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("perm_id", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.perm_id)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

In controller `ViewBag.perm_id` contains some values (this is foreign key). In view `perm.id` displays in the form of dropdownbox but I want it in the form of checkboxlist. How can I achieve this?

This is the viewmodel I created.

```
public class AssignUserViewModel
{
    public tm_perm_level[] perms { get; set; }
    public int grp_id { get; set; }
}
```

Now in controller how can i send values to view? This is my `tm_perm_level` model

```
public partial class tm_perm_level
{
    public tm_perm_level()
    {
        this.ts_grp_perm_mapping = new HashSet<ts_grp_perm_mapping>();
    }
    public int perm_id { get; set; }
    public string perm_levelname { get; set; }
    public string perm_description { get; set; }
    public bool perm_status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ts_grp_perm_mapping> ts_grp_perm_mapping { get; set; }
}
```

This is `ts_grp_perm_mapping` model

```
public partial class ts_grp_perm_mapping
{
    public ts_grp_perm_mapping()
    {
        this.ts_perm_levelmapping = new HashSet<ts_perm_levelmapping>();
    }
    public int grp_permid { get; set; }
    public int grp_id { get; set; }
    public int perm_id { get; set; }
    public List<tm_perm_level> permissions { get; set; }

    public virtual tm_grp_group tm_grp_group { get; set; }
    public virtual tm_perm_level tm_perm_level { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ts_perm_levelmapping> ts_perm_levelmapping { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Create a view model containing a `bool IsSelectedProperty` and the other properties of `tm_perm_level` that you want in the view. Then use a `for` loop of `EditorTemplate` to display each item in the collection

Comment: How can i send values from controller to view?

Comment: The view model you have shown will not work. Are you wanting to display each available `tm_perm_level` in the view with an associated checkbox? And you need to show your models.

Comment: Yes i want to display in checkbox. Tm_perm_level contains peroperlties id,name,des and isselected(bool)

Comment: You need to edit your question with the model (not in comments)

Comment: I edited my question with required model

Comment: Need a break, bit will add an answer in 45 min or so. Are you still also wanting the dropdownlist that displays the `tm_grp_group` items as well?

Comment: Yes i want that also. Thanks in advcne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially when editing, always start with view models to represent what you want to display (refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc))

```
public class PermissionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
public class GroupPermissionVM
{
  public int GroupID { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupList { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<PermissionVM> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Then create an `EditorTemplate` for `PermissionVM`. In the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PermissionVM.cshtml` folder

```
@model PermissionVM
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsSelected, Model.Name)
</div>
```

and the main view will be

```
@model GroupPermissionVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // dropdownlist
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GroupID)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupID, Model.GroupList, "Please select")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GroupID)
    // checkboxlist
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Permissions)

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

The controller methods would then be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var groups = db.tm_grp_group;
    var permissions = db.tm_perm_level;

    GroupPermissionVM model = new GroupPermissionVM
    {
        GroupList = new SelectList(groups, "grp_id", "grp_name"),
        Permissions = permissions.Select(p => new PermissionVM
        {
            ID = p.perm_id,
            Name = p.perm_levelname
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(GroupPermissionVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var groups = db.tm_grp_group;
        model.GroupList = new SelectList(groups, "grp_id", "grp_name");
        return View(model);
    }
    // map the view model to a new instance of your data model(s)
    // note: to get the ID's of the selected permissions - 
    //    var selectedPermissions = model.Permissions.Where(p => p.IsSelected).Select(p => p.ID);
    // save and redirect
}
```

Side note: I strongly recommend you follow normal naming conventions

**Edit**

Based on OP's comment for an option using radio buttons to select only one item, the revised code would be

```
public class PermissionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class GroupPermissionVM
{
  public int GroupID { get; set; }
  public int PermissionID { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupList { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<PermissionVM> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

and the view would be (no separate `EditorTemplate` required)

```
@model GroupPermissionVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // dropdownlist as above

    // radio buttons
    foreach (var permission in Model.Permissions)
    {
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonForm(m => m.PermissionID, permission.ID)
            <span>@permission.Name</span>
        </label>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

and in the POST method, the value of `model.PermissionID` will contain the `ID` of the selected Permission.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will implement now.

Comment: I am able to populate checkboxes but there is some issue with this sentence  GroupList = new SelectList(groups, "grp_id", "grp_name"), and the error message is cannot implicitly convert type system.web.mvc.selectlistitem to system.collections.generic.IEnumerable<system.web.webpages.html.selectlistitem> an explicit conversion is exist(are you missing cast)?

Comment: Can you tell me this line? i mean logic @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsSelected, Model.Name)

Comment: You have a wrong `using` statement in the controller or the model. It should be `@using System.Web.Mvc;`

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsSelected, Model.Name)` generates a label associated with the checkbox (and displays the `Name` property). When you click on the label it checks (or unchecks the associated checkbox)

Comment: Its working fine now. Thanks a lot Mr. Stephen Muecke. Struggling lot from one week. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have little doubt. If i want to save the data then i used   db.GroupPermissionVM.Add(model); but GroupPermissionVM is a view model which not exist in db. I am supposed to save data to ts_grp_perm_mapping table. So how can i save data to ts_grp_perm_mapping?

Comment: The opposite of the GET method, e.g. `var data = new ts_grp_perm_mapping { grp_id = model.GroupID }; db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Add(data); db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Note also there are tools such as [automapper](http://automapper.org/) which can make this easier

Comment: I accepted. My friend told if i marked as answered they never reply so i reopened and asked doubt. Thanks a lot Stephen

Comment: Don't listen to your friend (we are here to help) :)

Comment: Sure stephen. Yes I will get  grp_id=model.GroupID, but perm_id how can i get? Will it be something like this? perm_id=model.Permissions.?

Comment: i tried this  perm_id=selectedPermissions; but error is coming cannot implicitly convert type system.generec.collections.IEnumerable<int>  to int

Comment: See the note in the code `var selectedPermissions = model.Permissions.Where(p => p.IsSelected).Select(p => p.ID);` gives you the ID's of the selected permissions but your model does not seem to have a virtual property for `ICollection<tm_perm_level>` so I suspect there is something wrong with your data model (you do have `virtual tm_perm_level tm_perm_level` but that's just for one object, not a collection)

Comment: I dont figure out where i am going wrong? Di i need to make any changes in my model? Model is already posted above

Comment: All your data has is `virtual tm_perm_level tm_perm_level` (and you don't even have a navigation property for it). If you want a collection of `tm_perm_level` associated with a `ts_grp_perm_mapping` then you data model needs `virtual ICollection<tm_perm_level> permissons`. I suspect you have problems with your database design. If you can't work it out, you need to ask a new question showing you database structure and the data models - this thread is already too long (and when you do, I suggest you explain what all those cryptic names actually mean so its easier to understand)

Comment: okay stephen i will close conservation here. Anyway you helped me lot. Thank you

Comment: I got small doubt. Sorry for adding conversation here. In the above code if i want radiobutton instead of checkbox can i try something like this @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.perm_status) but it needs one more parameter. Can i have some suggestion?

Comment: So I assume you now only want to select one item from the collection, not  1 or more? If that's the case, you need a slightly different view model. Please confirm and I'll update the answer with the alternative

Comment: You said last time i have problem with db. you are just brilliant. Now i understood the situation clearly

Comment: Give me 45 min or so and I will edit my answer with the alternative. I'll ping you when its done :)

Comment: Thanks a lot stephen

Comment: Thanks a lot stephen

Comment: i edited but in view i am getting this error Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@".

Comment: Then remove the `@` before the word `foreach` - it all depends on you html structure as to whether you need to or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102659/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-luthfi-abdul-kader).